# In Doomemacs how to get "SPC q l" to automatically run the moment doom loads after I run "emacs .&" from command line

Tags: init-file, dired, customize, doom

On my linux box when I run `emacs .&` from the command line, inside a folder it opens up and displays that folders contents via Dired.

I need to either:

1. display the Doom landing screen instead of Dired or
2. run "spc q l" (reload last session) automatically.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to include the dot `.` in your command? If you do not include the dot in your command, then Doom should open at the 'landing screen'.

Comment: @dalanicolai Yes, I'm sure. without the ".&" Doom will only open the "last session" not the "session specific to this directory". If you get my meaning.

Comment: Too bad... I do not understand what you mean, I am not a Doom user. In vanilla Emacs this 'solution' works (it does not open a 'last session' by default). Okay, good luck then...